# Как сделать Listview кликабельным вместе с SearchView? - Java

Tags: java, android, listview, android-search-view

Если без SearchView, то можно использовать это так:

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                
                if (position==0){
                    soundPlay(s1);
                }

        });
```

А если использовать это вместе с SearchView, внося любое слово в строку меняется местоположение слов в ListView, то есть вот это:

```
                if (position==0){
                    soundPlay(s1);
                }
```

Уже некоректно.

Я же хочу узнать, как можно присвоить клик просто к слову`list_view.add("Слово",// и тут как то кликабельность прибавить);`, а не к позиции, ну или как там можно это сделать.

На ютубе есть ролики https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QDTiOUOfKQ, но они не подходят, они просто передают String На новый активити, а мне нужно воспроизвести звук

Comment: Сравнить в условии само слово вместо позиции, например.

Comment: @woesss Как это сделать ? ```if (//тут\\){soundPlay(hey)}```

Comment: @woesss что писать в условии?

Comment: Что-то вроде `if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Ваше слово"))`

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил! Спасибо за помощь @woesss !
Вы мне очень помогли.

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Ваше слово")){
soundPlay(s1);
}
```